# Why __isset() is not triggered in Laravel Model?

Tags: php, laravel-5, magic-methods

I have a Laravel project with this code:

```
$names = isset($user->party->personName->first_name) ? $user->party->personName->first_name . ' ' . $user->party->personName->last_name : null;

$role = $user->userRole->role->name ?? null
```

On the dev server this is working. On Homestead `$names` and `$role` are always `null`. As I know `isset()` should trigger `__isset()` method in the `Model` class but id does not.

> Laravel version - 5.2.31
>
> PHP on dev server - 7.0.2
>
> PHP on Homestead - 7.0.8-2+deb.sury.org~xenial+1

Is this because the difference of the PHP versions or there is some setting?

Comment: why should it? `isset()` is a PHP core function. That's a perfectly valid procedural function call.

Comment: `first_name` is dynamic property. It is not defined in the `User` class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behaviour changed in PHP 7.0.6. You can reproduce a basic example using the following:

```
class Foo {
  public function __isset($arg) {
    echo '__isset called', PHP_EOL;
  }
}

$foo = new Foo;

echo 'Basic:', PHP_EOL;
isset($foo->property);

echo 'Deep:', PHP_EOL;
isset($foo->property->child);
```

Before 7.0.6, the `__isset` method was only called for the top-level property, whereas now it's called for the deeper, child property as well.

See https://3v4l.org/D389q for the different results.

It looks to stem back to a fix applied for this bug: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69659

Answer (score -1):

`__isset()` is called when you are do `isset()` on an object, when __isset() is defined in the class.

make a `debug_print_backtrace` in the __isset method, to see if its really called

But what if any of the selected variables before tha last isnt set?

`isset($user->party->personName->first_name)`

Comment: `__isset()` is defined in Laravel's `Model` class. This code works on the dev server, but not on Homestead.

Comment: so `personName` is a Model Class with a dynamic property called `first_name`?

Comment: `party` and `personName` are relations in Laravel, they are already defined. `first_name` is a dynamic property.